# "kommen" + Infinitiv

Tags: verb

Häufig werden die Formen ***'sein + Infinitiv'*** und ***'gehen + Infinitiv'*** benutzt:

> Ich bin/war essen. (sein + Infinitiv)
>
> Ich gehe essen. / Ich bin essen gegangen. (gehen + Infinitiv)

Ist aber die Struktur ***'kommen + Infinitiv'*** richtig bzw. wird im Deutschen tatsächlich benutzt? - Zum Beispiel:

> Er kommt gleich essen.
>
> Sie ist gestern mit ihrem Mann essen gekommen.

Ich habe noch nie sowas gehört und klingt mir zwar ein bisschen komisch. Es kann aber sein, dass diese Form trotzdem richtig oder einfach nur Umgangssprache ist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, diese Struktur wird sogar relativ oft benutzt, allerdings tatsächlich nur umgangssprachlich.

Und in deinem Fall auch in einem etwas anderen Kontext (zuhause am Küchentisch, wohingegen essen sein/essen gehen sich auf tatsächliches "ausgehen" im Restaurant beziehen).

> Ich komme gleich essen, muss nur noch kurz etwas fertig machen!

In einer Nacherzählung oder Schriftsprache würde ich eine derartige Formulierung vermeiden, zum Beispiel klingt

> Sie ist gestern mit ihrem Mann essen gekommen.

tatsächlich sehr merkwürdig. Vom Gefühl her würde ich diese Struktur nur für zeitlich unmittelbare Handlung verwenden, selbst bei dieser nur leicht zeitlich versetzten Frage (immer noch im Präsens) ist es schon üblich, die Formulierung zu ändern:

> Kommst du nachher zum Essen?

Comment: «Sie ist gestern mit ihrem Mann essen gekommen» tönt für mich völlig normal und akzeptabel. Ich halte keine dieser Konstruktionen für umgangssprachlich.

Comment: Interessant. Wo kommst du her? Die Verwendung von "tönen" deutet auf den Alpenraum.